# Trying to use Zebra Printer via ZPL on Python

Tags: python, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print a monochrome png file using "zpl" and "zebra" modules on Python. My labels have 4 inches in width and 1-inch in height. I tried to take a ZPL code from zpl libraries. It gives me the right zpl. I am entering that zpl to Labelary ZPL Viewer and it views the content of it but the printer isn't printing anything when I send that ZPL to the printer. Also, I am using zpl. output for sending it to the printer. The printer's LED flashes one time and then nothing happens. I've also tried to download Zebra Setup Utility and I sent this zpl to a printer from there and the result was the same. Here is the code that I am using to print. I need to handle that situation immediately so I'd be appreciated to any ideas.

```
from PIL import Image
import zpl
from zebra import Zebra
class Print:

 def __init__(self):
  self.zebra = Zebra()
  self.printers = self.zebra.getqueues()


 def print(self, queue, height, width):
    z = Zebra(queue)
    label = zpl.Label(height, width, 8)
    label.write_graphic(Image.open("barcodes/toPrinter.png"), width)
    z.output(label.dumpZPL())
    label.preview()
```

Here is my ZPL :

`^XA^FO0,0^GFA,41412,20726,102,0000000000000000000000and rest of image data...^FS^XZ`

Comment: The picture data of the ``^GF`` command normally needs to be a 1-bit bitmap image!

Answer (score 0):

PNG images have inconsistent support in most zebra printers. For example, the `^GF` command appears to only support GRF images on many firmware versions.  The most portable way to work with PNG images is to use the `~DY` command to download and save the image to the printer.  Then use `^IL` to render the image (note that `^IL` always positions at `0,0`).  Or use the `^IM` command to position the PNG using `^FO`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I don't want to position the png. I want to cover all of the label. I'll research how can i use ~DY and ^IL commands. Thanks